# Marketing Cloud Approvals

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration

We are testing Workflows & Approvals in Marketing Cloud (Standard Approval Process) and have run into an issue where our approver user in the Workflow Team, which is has the roles "Administrator" and "Marketing Cloud Administrator" does not get the option to Decline the approval items. At the "Reviewed" stage, the only options available to the final approver user are Submit Comments, Approve, Edit, Delete.

I've also tried enabling all permissions for "Approvals (Email)" for this user.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was rectified by support in the back end, due to certain components not being fully deployed when the account was provisioned.